# Compute the operator norm of this linear transformation

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Im having trouble understanding how to compute the operator norm of
the linear transformation defined by:
$$
L\left(x,y\right)=\left(x+3y,y-x\right)
$$
I know the operator norm is defined by
$$
\left\Vert L\right\Vert =\max_{\left|\left(x,y\right)\right|=1}\left|L\left(x,y\right)\right|
$$
So i thought calculating this might help:
$$
\left|L\left(x,y\right)\right|^{2}=\left(x+3y\right)^{2}+\left(y-x\right)^{2}=\ldots=2\left(x+y\right)^{2}+8y^{2}
$$
But how do i maximize this over the unit sphere?

I wanna say it is maximized when $y=1$ but how do I prove it?

Moreover, is the operator norm of a general linear transformation related
somehow to the eigenvalues of its corresponding matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the norm is related to the eigenvalues. More precisely,
$$||L|| = \sup \{ \sqrt{\lambda} \ | \ \lambda \in \sigma (A^T A) \}$$
where $\sigma (A^T A)$ denotes the eigenvalues of $A^T A$. In this particular case, it looks like the operator norm is $1+\sqrt{5} \approx 3.2361$